# CSS3 animation issue in IE11

Tags: html, css, css-animations, internet-explorer-11

I am facing an issue in css3 animation in IE11 only.

Here is link with issue (please open in ie11)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".spinnerTinyBar").show();
  $("#toggle").click(function() {
    $(".spinnerTinyBar").toggle();
  });
});
```

```css
@keyframes tinybar-load1 {
  0% {
    box-shadow: 0 0 blue;
    height: 20px;
  }
  40% {
    box-shadow: 0 -15px blue;
    height: 25px;
  }
  80% {
    box-shadow: 0 0 blue;
    height: 20px;
  }
  100% {
    box-shadow: 0 0 blue;
    height: 20px;
  }
}

.spinnerTinyBar,
.spinnerTinyBar:before,
.spinnerTinyBar:after {
  background: blue;
  animation: tinybar-load1 1s infinite ease-in-out;
  width: 2px;
  height: 20px;
}

.spinnerTinyBar:before {
  left: -5px;
  -webkit-animation-delay: -0.32s;
  animation-delay: -0.32s;
}

.spinnerTinyBar {
  font-size: 9px;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-animation-delay: -0.16s;
  animation-delay: -0.16s;
  transform: translateZ(0);
}

.spinnerTinyBar:after {
  left: 5px;
}

.spinnerTinyBar:before,
.spinnerTinyBar:after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="button" id="toggle" value="Toggle" />
<div class="spinnerTinyBar"></div>
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/e45q5/16/)

Issue: 
For first time, the animation is working good. When I toggle by clicking on toggle button the animation is not happening for 1st and last bar. This is working fine in chrome and in all mobile devices.

Let me know if anybody figured it out and do the needful

Comment: The code you have make is perfect it should be work. May be its seem like cache related issues please hard refresh your browser (ctrl + F5) and (ctrl + r).

Comment: @Hemdip - I tried hard refresh as you said. Didn't work

Comment: have you tried adding the -ms prefix for the animations ?

Comment: @Mr.x - Nope. Wont work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a weird one this but here's a fix:

Change your html to this:

```
<body>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){
            $(".spinnerTinyBar").show();
            $("#toggle").click(function(){
            $(".divClass").toggleClass('spinnerTinyBar');

            });
            });

        </script>
        <input type="button" id="toggle" value="Toggle"/>
        <div class="divClass spinnerTinyBar"></div>
    </body>
```

Instead of hiding the element we simply change the class on it to show the animation, or not

[Here's an updated fiddle working in ie11](http://jsfiddle.net/e45q5/27/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this little hack for your IE

```
@media screen and (min-width: 0\0) {
  .your-animation-parent {
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
   }
}
```